# compile .c with gcc

Tags: c, gcc

I'm trying to compile a program that have main.c and  a lot of .c and .h files .
Is there any way to compile and link  without passing all .c file in the gcc command
like

```
gcc  main.c file.c file2.c -o main
```

Comment: Learn how to write `Makefile`s, you won't regret it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your shell can expand wildcards. So you can:

```
gcc *.c -o main
```

Of course, you'll have to make sure that you don't have any extra `*.c` files in the directory that you don't actually want compiled. A better option is to use a build system such as Make or SCons.

Comment: but if there is a . c in the same directory that i don't want to be included .

Comment: Yes, use a build script system such as Make or SCons. Doing this by hand is not sustainable.

Comment: what i'm looking for is a simple way to just give him the file that contain the main (main.c) and he find the rest

Comment: @unfamous: C doesn't work that way, since file names mean nothing to the compiler or linker (just to you). So if you have a `main.c` that calls a function `foo()`, how would the compiler know where to look for it? Even if you declare it in a `foo.h` header file, the corresponding `.c` file could have any name.

Answer (score 3):

'make' is the tool for building C apps. Below is the hello world version.

```
$ cat main.c 
#include <stdio.h>

int main (char *argv[], int argc) {
    printf("Hello World\n"); 
    return 0; 
}
$ make main
cc     main.c   -o main
$ ./main 
Hello World
```

**Edited in deference to Shahbaz comment**:
The original question was trying to simplify the command-line for gcc. The right direction for the programmer is to learn about make. Since there is a bit of a learning curve with make, I wanted to offer simple stepping stone which does something useful. By getting started in this way, you don't need a make file. Simply type 'make programname' as shown above. Make uses its default rules and associated varabiles. $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS)  The astute programmer can build on this by setting well-know variables.

From here one can tinker with a makefile. In the spirit of stepping stones, consider this trival makefile

```
$ cat makefile 

SRCS = main.c
OBJ = ${SRCS:.c=.o}
CC=gcc

main: ${OBJ}

$ make
gcc   main.o   -o main
```

By setting the well-known make variable CC to control which compiler is used.  OBJ is computed from the list of source files. The trival target starts one on the road to rules.

Anyway, my hope is this post and other answers get the original questioner on there way.

Regards,
-jk

Comment: Shouldn't the hello world version focus on the contents of the `Makefile` rather than the program?

Answer (score 0):

```
gcc -o main -I. `find . -name "*\.c"`
```

This way you could have the .c and .h files in subfolders if you wish.

However, this is not a good way of doing it. A better way would be to create a [Makefile](http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/)

Comment: But that will include all files in that directory.what happen if i there is a file i don't want to be used

Comment: Then you go ahead and create a Makefile :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking about the command-line, you can just use wildcards to specify all the .c files as @Man of One Way suggested. But in general, C applications of any-but-trivial-size are built using "makefiles" which are *extremely* helpful.

You might want to read a tutorial such as http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2002/cmsc214/Tutorial/makefile.html

Answer (score 0):

As already said, make is the best way to go
Learn just what you need at every point

Besides, it is important to also use some flags that will help you out while coding:

```
-Wall -> sets all warning flags
-g, -ggdb -> generates debug code
-ansi, -std=c99
```

A really good book on how to use make is,
http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780937175903.do